# Can a Windows PC act as a Bluetooth beacon?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon

Does a normal Windows (8.1) PC have the ability to act as a Bluetooth LE beacon? If so, is there any software to enable that?

## Update

More current answers here: 
[Beacons in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035696/beacons-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre-Windows 10, Windows 8.1 in your case, doesn't support scanning or acting as iBeacon(s) nativly. However, you have some options:

- Use the [WinBeacon](https://github.com/huysentruitw/win-beacon) managed library (yes, I'm the owner). Replace the driver of the Bluetooth 4.0 dongle with a libusb/WinUSB driver and you're all set
- Use a VM that runs linux with BlueZ stack
- Use a RaspberryPI as 'detector' that hosts a WebAPI interface to your Windows machine
- Switch to [Windows 10](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-10-will-support-ibeacon-technology/)

Comment: Doesn't appear that Windows 10 gives you the ability to actually beacon. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementpublisher

Comment: I see Windows 10 mentioned everywhere, so not sure what is not supported. In each case, the WinBeacon library still works on Windows 10 so that's still an option.

Answer (score -4):

Bluetooth low energy or Bluetooth LE, marketed as Bluetooth Smart, is a wireless personal area network technology designed and marketed by the Bluetooth Special Interest Group aimed at novel applications in the healthcare, fitness, security, and home entertainment industries.

Mobile operating systems including iOS, Android, Windows Phone and BlackBerry, as well as OS X, Linux, and **Windows 8**, natively support Bluetooth Smart.

I found software for Bluetooth 4.0 for windows 8 (64 bits) here http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds037617

Comment: A beacon (ab)uses the advertisement data of the BLE specification, nothing more. It is not a BLE device as such... Windows 8.1 might support BLE devices, but there is no API to read or setup the advertisement data. Therefore, there's no native (i)Beacon support.